# Print the final result at the end of whole loop

Tags: python

The code block looks like

```
regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']

data = []
header = ["Port","Open For","Security group","Instance Details"]

    for region in regions:
        connection=ec2.connect_to_region(region)
        sg = connection.get_all_security_groups()
        try:
            for securityGroup in sg:
               for rule in securityGroup.rules:
                   if '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                      for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                          instanceId=str(instanceid)
                         # print instanceId
                          tag = getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])
                          if tag is not None:
                            # print tab              
                               tab =[str(rule.to_port),"0.0.0.0/0",str(securityGroup.name),str(getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1]))]
                               data.append(tab)
            print tabulate(data, headers=header, tablefmt='simple')
```

This produces the result as :

```
  Port  Open For    Security group           Instance Details
------  ----------  -----------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 65535  0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-mingjun    (u'testVM10001', u'192.168.0.93', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-mingjun    (u'testVM10001', u'192.168.0.93', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   SSH+HTTPS                (u'security_monkey_production', u'172.30.2.31', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   SSH+HTTPS                (u'security_monkey_production', u'172.30.2.31', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
   443  0.0.0.0/0   SSH+HTTPS                (u'security_monkey_production', u'172.30.2.31', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   na-prod-1w-secgroup      (u'na-prod-1w-scc-94a54e56', u'10.197.51.19', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
```

Waits here for sometime and then prints

```
  Port  Open For    Security group           Instance Details
------  ----------  -----------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 65535  0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-mingjun    (u'testVM10001', u'192.168.0.93', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-mingjun    (u'testVM10001', u'192.168.0.93', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   SSH+HTTPS                (u'security_monkey_production', u'172.30.2.31', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   SSH+HTTPS                (u'security_monkey_production', u'172.30.2.31', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
   443  0.0.0.0/0   SSH+HTTPS                (u'security_monkey_production', u'172.30.2.31', RegionInfo:us-east-1)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   na-prod-1w-secgroup      (u'na-prod-1w-scc-94a54e56', u'10.197.51.19', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
   443  0.0.0.0/0   na-prod-1w-secgroup      (u'na-prod-1w-scc-94a54e56', u'10.197.51.19', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   sfo01-devops-haproxy-sg  (u'sfo01-cwptest-LBi-f207da47', u'192.168.80.171', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   sfo01-devops-haproxy-sg  (u'sfo01-cwptest-LBi-e1a72422', u'192.168.80.156', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
   443  0.0.0.0/0   sfo01-devops-haproxy-sg  (u'sfo01-cwptest-LBi-f207da47', u'192.168.80.171', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
   443  0.0.0.0/0   sfo01-devops-haproxy-sg  (u'sfo01-cwptest-LBi-e1a72422', u'192.168.80.156', RegionInfo:us-west-1)
 65535  0.0.0.0/0   Nishant-Open             (u'POC-demo-es/kib', u'10.205.11.150', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    22  0.0.0.0/0   Nishant-Open             (u'POC-demo-es/kib', u'10.205.11.150', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
  5601  0.0.0.0/0   Nishant-Open  
....
```

why not in one go??

Comment: Just push data to a dictionary or list and parse it once the loop finishes. Should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do before for loop starts create list variables called `data` and `header`

```
data = []
header = ["Port","Open For","Security group","Instance Details"]
for region in regions:
    # your code....
    .
    .
    .
    if tag is not None:
        tab =[str(rule.to_port),"0.0.0.0/0",str(securityGroup.name),str(getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1]))]    
        data.append(tab)
print tabulate(data, headers=header, tablefmt='grid')
```

Comment: something wrong with the indentation of last print statement

Comment: can you show the error??, you need to put print statement when 1st for loop ends

Comment: on it.. just hang in there

Comment: I got your point.. working on it.. i need to send the notification to slack too.. i am gonna accept the answer soon,,. thanks for the help..

Comment: @NishantSingh Welcome :)

Comment: Hey man , you there.. the script doesn't print the whole result in one go.. basically it breakes up the result.. i am updating the question and result for you

Comment: @NishantSingh Dident got you, can you explain briefly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109879/discussion-between-nishant-singh-and-hackaholic).

Answer (score 0):

Store the values of tag in dictionary or even listand print the dictionary at the end of the program. you can use print format to print in the tabular form.